# Как сделать цикл через php и mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, while

Как сделать цикл через php и mysql? Как добавить `echo '<div>Реклама</div>';` после 2 запись и повторяется каждый раз? Например:

```
1
2
echo '<div>Реклама</div>';
3
4
echo '<div>Реклама</div>';
5
6
echo '<div>Реклама</div>';
и т.д.
```

Пример код

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$post = mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// Цикл
}
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что, по-вашему, означает сочетание букв `while` в вашем коде?

Comment: Вы что, не можете вставить вывод слова перед `}` в цикле? P.S. Функции `mysql_` **устарели**! Уберите их из своего кода навсегда.

Comment: @KYRAN так и что мешает писать вместо `$post_id = $row['post_id']; echo $post_id; `  просто `echo $row['post_id'].'<br />'; ` ???  Добавляя "слов" в конце

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С вашим кодом будет примерно так:

это если заменить каждый третий

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0)
        echo '<div>Реклама</div>';
    else 
        echo 'Что-то там из массива';

    ++$i
}
?>
```

То есть, логически если рассуждать, вам надо вставить рекламу в каждый третий блок. Соответственно в цикле вы смотрите на счетчик. Если счетчик получается поделить на 3 без остатка, то тогда выводим рекламу, а если нет - то остальное.

Если хотите добавить после каждого второго, как в примере.. тогда тут надо проверять остаток от деления на 2

```
<?php
    $query="SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo 'Что-то там из массива';

        if ($i % 2 == 0)
            echo '<div>Реклама</div>';

        ++$i
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо работает но заменяет каждый 3 `запись` на `реклама` а как сделать чтобы не заменить просто после него добавить?

Comment: @KYRAN подправил ответ. В том случае, если хотите выводить контент после каждой рекламы, тогда просто условия `else` не должно быть

Answer (score 3):

Если я вас правильно понял, то

```
$select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table"); // $db - PDO
$select->execute();
$rows = $select->fetchAll();
$i = 1;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo 'вывод из базы';

    if($i % 3 == 0)
        echo '<div>Реклама</div>';

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Нажмите на кнопку править в вашем посте и подробнее опишите ваш вопрос.

Comment: @KYRAN  а я ответ